# WSS connection failed for https

Tags: ssl, websocket, xampp

I am forcing a dummy SSL for my localhost running through xampp. Now I am using web sockets which asks for 'wss:' instead of 'ws:'. But when using 'wss', I am getting the following Error:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://192.168.1.5/?aswin' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled

I am new to this, I don't know what's causing this issue.

Comment: see if this similar post would help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818174/webbit-websocket-ws-connection-works-but-wss-handshake-fails-silently-with?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remember to change the port number to a one different to the one you used for not secure connections. Some browsers get confused if suddenly a port becomes secure or viceversa.
- Remember to use the hostname indicated in the certificate to connect and not the IP.
- If you are using a self-signed certificate, use it for HTTPS so you can see the dialog for accepting that certificate. When accessing via WSS:// there is not certificate acceptance dialog, it will just fail to connect.